# Picam preview shows on HDMI monitor, but not GPIO connected display. How to fix?

Tags: gpio, camera, hdmi, display, lcd

I'm making a project that requires an automatic and constant preview from the camera shown on a small LCD display.

I managed to have the camera preview upon the Pi startup by adding `raspivid -t 0 -f` to the `rc.local` file. I got everything working as intended on an HDMI monitor.

However, when I connected the display (https://www.waveshare.com/1.28inch-lcd-module.htm), I got nothing shown.

I think the official document states that camera preview is not supported on GPIO displays. If so, is there any workaround for this, or do I just have to find an alternative approach?

The final product will use a Pi Zero 2 W, but I'm currently doing this on a Pi 3B+ as I wait for the Zero to be shipped. I'm also running Raspberry Pi OS (Released 2022-04-04).

Comment: are you able to display the linux desktop on the LCD?

Comment: Hi there @jsotola, sorry I forgot to give an update here. But after some further research, it seems that this method is just implausible for now. Fortunately, I could achieve the same thing in a cheaper and simpler way with the ESP32-CAM board and LCD display. I wonder if I can close down or delete my original question?